# ruby ffi call function referenced by pointer in struct?

Tags: ruby, ffi, ruby-ffi

I'm trying to use libfluidsynth with ruby ffi and need to iterate over a soundfont to get all instruments.  Specifically, the _fluid_sfont_t struct has iteration_start and iteration_next references that I need to call:

http://fluidsynth.sourceforge.net/api/struct__fluid__sfont__t.html

```
void (*iteration_start)(fluid_sfont_t* sfont);
```

I saw in the ffi/ffi documentation how to reference members of a struct where those members were normal types and I saw how to set callbacks in C to point to ruby Procs.  However I need to call a function referenced by a function pointer on a struct.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this link help?  https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/404